# importing CSS into a HTML does not work.

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, frontend

I am trying to import CSS file into an HTML but it does not work. I did try linking also. Can anyone have an idea why? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lesson</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    @import url("U5.css");
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="U5.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Does `href="U5.css"` helps or you are exactly looking for inline import?

Comment: I did try href="U5.css"  also but not works. No I am not looking for inline import.

Comment: Test the CSS with [a validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and use the Developer Tools in your browser to see what URL is being requested for the CSS and what the server says when it responds to that request.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, I am going to try it now.

Comment: have you tried `@import "U5.css"`

Comment: Yes I did try Ali Sheikhpour.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because it's not in the right path? For my example, the style sheet is stored at path/to/stylesheet:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    @import url("/path/to/stylesheet/U5.css");
</style>
```

But could I ask why you aren't including the stylesheet like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/stylesheet/U5.css">
```

Comment: I did try all the possible ways but still does not work. I only can use linking or @import for pass to my lesson. I am not allowed use inline. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: No problem, where abouts is your stylesheet stored if I can ask?

It might help me come up with a better solution for you.

Comment: ''\VT17WebUtvMahmutAlban\Assets\style\U5.css ''I am trying to call from this path.

Comment: Ah I see use forward slashes (/) instead of black slashes ( \ )

Comment: I did use instead of back but It did not work @connoraworden

Comment: Even when using /Assets/style/U5.css (I'm presuming that your html is storted at \VT17WebUtvMahmutAlban\)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

**Try This. Either one should work if the css file is stored somewhere on the web.**

Open the `U5.css` and copy its `location`.

For example if the file is hosted at **`https://www.somerandomwebsite.com/assets/css/U5.css`**

**Then** use the following :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.somerandomwebsite.com/assets/css/U5.css">
```

**Else** you can copy all the content of that particular `U5.css` *(assuming the U5.css file is stored somewhere else)* and paste it into a new `css file` and store that `css file` in a `folder` in your project.

Look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21GL6.png) for an idea.

**..**

**Try adding ~/**

```
~/your path here/U5.css
```

A good book to read is Mastering Integrated HTML and CSS by Virginia DeBolt.

Comment: Thanks but It did not work.

Comment: Print is used as a media query. For example, when someone goes to print a page it will load the stylesheet for it so that it's "optimised" for print.

Comment: Where is the U5.css file stored?

Comment: Try this. This should work.
~/your path here/U5.css

Comment: ~/ gives you access to the root folder

Comment: It did not work @Wildchild

Answer (score 0):

I did validate first and got 3 errors but none of them are about importing.

[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bgBm.jpg)